# How can I prevent returning duplicate results using BigCommerce API and Python datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, bigcommerce

This program I've developed is supposed to return a list of all orders placed since the last time it was ran. It executes twice daily, once at 6AM and once at 12PM.

Currently it compares order dates to the date value returned by the function `calculate_min_date(datetime)`. However, there is an issue where some orders are being returned two executions in a row. For example, an order placed at 9AM gets returned by the 12PM execution as expected, but then it also gets returned by the following day's 6AM execution. It should not be returned a second time. I believe there's something wrong with how I'm formatting or comparing dates.

Get date:

```
def calculate_min_date(now):
    then = now
    if now.hour < 7:
        # if time is 6am, get orders since 12pm yesterday (-18 hours)
        then = now + timedelta(hours=-18)
    else:
        # if time is 12pm, get orders since 6am today (-6 hours)
        then = now + timedelta(hours=-6)
    # reset datetime with no minutes or seconds
    target_date = datetime(then.year, then.month, then.day, then.hour)
    # return datetime formatted as ISO-8601
    return utils.format_datetime(target_date)
```

Get orders since date using BigCommerce API. Using the `min_date_created` API parameter to do so, which returns an ISO-8601 datetime formatted as `2023-06-07T09:26:09.000-04:00`:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-management/orders#get-all-orders

```
def get_orders_since(self, min_date_created):
        order_list = []
        while True:
            try:
                orders = self._api.Orders.all(
                    min_date_created=min_date_created, limit=250)
                if type(orders) != list:
                    break
                order_list.extend(orders)
                while len(order_list) % 250 == 0:
                    last_id = order_list[-1]['id']
                    orders = self._api.Orders.all(
                        min_date_created=min_date_created, limit=250, min_id=last_id)
                    if type(orders) == list:
                        order_list.extend(orders)
            except HttpException as e:
                print(Fore.YELLOW, 'get_orders_since(%s) produced an error' %
                      id, Style.RESET_ALL)
                print(Fore.YELLOW, str(e), Style.RESET_ALL)
                time.sleep(0.25)
                return self.get_orders_since(min_date_created)
            break
        successful_order_ids = [2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
        real_orders = [
            o for o in order_list if o.status_id in successful_order_ids]
        return real_orders
```

Main function:

```
def main():
    now = datetime.now()
    min_date_created = calculate_min_date(now)
    orders = get_orders_since(min_date_created)
    
    # Send orders via FTP...
```

Logs of a duplicate order:

Finds order 145 the first time during the 12:00:02 PM execution

```
06/07/2023 06:00:03 AM Starting up @ Wed, 07 Jun 2023 06:00:03 -0000...
06/07/2023 06:00:03 AM Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api...
06/07/2023 06:00:03 AM No orders since Tue, 06 Jun 2023 12:00:00 -0000
06/07/2023 12:00:02 PM Starting up @ Wed, 07 Jun 2023 12:00:02 -0000...
06/07/2023 12:00:02 PM Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api...
06/07/2023 12:00:03 PM Order 145 found - Order Date: 2023-06-07T09:26:09.000-04:00
06/07/2023 12:00:04 PM OK! FTP successful
```

Incorrectly finds the same order again during the next day's 06:00:03 AM execution

```
06/08/2023 06:00:03 AM Starting up @ Thu, 08 Jun 2023 06:00:03 -0000...
06/08/2023 06:00:03 AM Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api...
06/08/2023 06:00:03 AM Order 145 found - Order Date: 2023-06-07T09:26:09.000-04:00
06/08/2023 06:00:04 AM OK! FTP successful
06/08/2023 12:00:03 PM Starting up @ Thu, 08 Jun 2023 12:00:03 -0000...
06/08/2023 12:00:03 PM Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api...
06/08/2023 12:00:03 PM No orders since Thu, 08 Jun 2023 06:00:00 -0000
```